# Spinning Wheel Concept in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas, android-menu

In one my project i want to use a spinning wheel. 
No. of sectors, color and text used to fill those sectors will come from API response.
I need to create a circle(Center aligned in the screen) dynamically and split it according to the number of sectors and fill text and color. Then Spin the circle for 2-3 seconds and stop it at a position (Arrow pointing at bottom of circle). This position also from Webservice response.

What will be the best way to achieve this.

Currently iam using the below project as a reference
https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu

Here the pointer is positioned at top. how to shift it at the bottom of circle. And also how to apply the spin animation (Mentioned above)

Thanks in Advance !! :-)

Comment: I reckon you need to override this method -> `setAlternateTopDiv()` present in the library.

Comment: Thanks it worked.. but really im stuck with spinning animation and stopping it at desired sector position.

Comment: what you can do is make that circular image and then rotate it yourself. I think that might just be easier for you. Or can take a  look at [this](https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView)